# Web Server Access Error

Tags: java, android, sql-server, apache, phpmyadmin

I am building an Android App that connects to remote DB with the help of PHP API stored on a Apache Server.

Here is how it is planned:

(1) User Click Login on App
(2) App makes call to login.php on a Web Server
(3) login.php then checks on phpmyadmin SQL server (specific db and tables for user details)

Now, I am having a problem!!

I am using an academic university server

Normally university allows me to access any file using following format:

For example,
http://doc.gold.ac.uk/~m00982/test.html

Here ~m00982 represents my student ID known to university.

Going back to my original problem. Whilst I can access my php files directly via web browser. But I have coded my Java in such a way that:

CustomHTTP Client checks first of all if URL address is ok and accessible.

I am getting error as CustomHTTPClient FALSE because it is unable to establish connection to doc.gold.ac.uk as access is denied by server. I am aware of this as university server would ask for a username and password to connect.

How can I resolve this issue???

If I USE a private web server (for example, I bought web hosting on Go Daddy) and store my files and folders there, It works perfectly and CustomHTTPClient TRUE in that case.

I need to use University Server as my SQL db is stored locally there which I need to run my app.

Any suggestions?

```
My CustomHTTPClient.Java snippet is here:

   public static boolean isAddressOk(String link){
        boolean isOK = false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection urlCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlCon.connect();
            if(urlCon.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                isOK = true;
                Log.i(DEBUG, "TRUE");
            }else{
                isOK = false;
                Log.i(DEBUG, "FALSE");
            }
            urlCon.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            isOK = false;
            Log.e(DEBUG, "FALSE");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isOK = false;
            Log.e(DEBUG, "FALSE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isOK;
    }
}
```

and Parameters are defined here:

```
// the URL for IGOR Web Server where PHP Scripts are located
public static final String LINK_ROOT = "http://doc.gold.ac.uk";

// the link to login API on IGOR Server
public static final String LINK_LOGIN = LINK_ROOT + "/~ma00982/android/login.php";
```